# How can I iterate over arrays of sub-arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of sub-arrays like this

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", nil]]
```

How can I iterate over this to create an html table whose sub-array is a column of the table as below?

```
a d g
b e h
c f
```

Comment: Will the sub arrays always be of equal length?

Comment: yes, they will always be equal length and will include nils to fill in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is your lucky day, ruby has just the thing for you, [Array#transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose).

```
ary = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", nil]]

ary.transpose.each {|a| p a }
# >> ["a", "d", "g"]
# >> ["b", "e", "h"]
# >> ["c", "f", nil]
```

Comment: I was happy with my use of `zip`, though had never heard of `transpose` :) Great answer, and a good one to know about. +1

Comment: @SRack In my 12 years of doing ruby I have used transpose maybe 5 times. 4 of those were stackoverflow answers :)

Comment: Great solution ! You could maybe incorporate @Rohan 's solution for a complete answer though

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you're after:

```
zipper = array.shift
puts zipper.zip(*array).map { |sub_array| sub_array.join(' ') }
```

So, you take the first element of the array and assign to a variable (`zipper` in this case).

You then `zip` the other arguments into this, and join them with a space as a separator.

Or, in one line:

```
array.shift.zip(*array)
```

When this is printed to the console, you get the output desired.

Comment: You can inline `zipper`, btw. You don't use it separately. `array.shift.zip(*array).map ...`

Answer (score 0):

As per the given description it seems like the below mentioned solution could work:

```
array.each do |f|
    <tr> # this will be row 
    f.each do |g|
       <th>g</th> # this will be column
    end
    </tr>
end
```

Comment: This prints arrays as rows, not columns.

Comment: second loop will print it as columns

Comment: No, it won't. It will print them as cells in a row.

Comment: You're producing a transposed matrix of the expected results, it needs to print the first element of each sub array, then in a new row it needs to print the second element of each sub array and so on